# MassTransit integration Aspnetboilerplate

Tags: masstransit, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I would like to integrate MassTransit with Aspnetboilerplate project to use RabbitMQ as distributed event bus. Then potentially look to integrate Azure Service bus.

I am struggling in how to create a simple Eventbus and implement register and subscribe. Unfortunately I cannot find any good examples of this being done.

I can use the Aspnetboilerplate EventBus without any issues. An example of what I am looking to achieve is the following:

```
 // subscribe to an event
var ev  = EventBus.Register<T>(eventInfo =>
{
   // do something with evInfo.Data
}
ev.Dispose();


// publish and event
private readonly IEventBus _eventBus;
_eventBus.TriggerAsync(new T());
```

I do not want to use the Abp framework due to licensing restriction on LGPL. The company that I work for will not accept this type of licenses in any of there internal products

Any advice or any article implementing something similar would be great.

**UPDATE 1**
As Chris pointed out lots of great videos and documentation and good to see for a great library.

Although I cannot seem to find any documentation how to implement a Generic Consumer / Request Client.

```
// Example of a consumer
public class ManagerResultConsumer<T>: BaseConsumer<ManagerResult<T>>
{
    public override Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ManagerResult<T>> context)
    {
        return base.Consume(context);
    }
}

// configure the service / consumers and clients
services.AddMediator(configurator =>
{
    configurator.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
    configurator.AddConsumer<ManagerResultConsumer<T>>();


    configurator.AddRequestClient<SubmitOrder>();
    configurator.AddRequestClient<ManagerResult<T>>();
});
```

I am trying to ensure I do not have register lots of concrete implementations at start up, similar to SubmitOrder and SubmitOrderConsumer.

Thanks

Comment: You can't have generic consumers, all types must closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking through [MassTransit's documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/), watching the myriad of [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx8uyNNs1ri2MBx6BjPum5j9_MMdIfM9C), and checking out [the samples](https://masstransit-project.com/learn/samples.html) showing how to build applications with MassTransit.

Comment: Thank you will do appreciate the links

Comment: Added an update to the existing problem after reading the documentation / videos